# How to improve human gender recognition based on face image?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, javacv, face-recognition

Now I'm doing human face gender recognition using javacv, The correctness is not very satisfactory for only about 70%. The training set I'm using is some asia human face images I get from internet, and I both used geometry info based training & classification and appearance based info.

The geometry info is produced by choosing some face feature points ratios such like faceheight/facewidth etc and trained by a fisher recognizor, while the appearance info is trained by a LBP face recognizor.

My question is: what is the key point to improve the correctness of gender recognition? Can someone share some experiences?

Thanks~

Comment: have you aligned your faces? for us it improved performance by about 15%. I also suggest you slightly enlarge the boundingbox returned from the face detector and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Yes, alreay did preprocess work including grayscaling, aligning, normalizing, tantrigg... I also enlarged the boudingbox by width*1.5 and height.1.5 for the face rect detected...

Comment: What do you mean by LBP face recognizer? I understand you are using LBP features. Are you implementing them by yourself? If not, have you verified the implementation is correct and appropriate. What classifier are you using? lda?  Have you tried svm with rbf kernel? Even in linear case, svm is usually superior.

Comment: How did you also get the 70% figure? Did you split the data into training and testing set(cross validation)?

Comment: Hi Lin, the LBP type recognizer is implemented by OPENCV. Yes, I splited the data into training and testing set. And I also changed the  recognizer type from LBP to Fisher， still not get better result.

Comment: Try to make use of FaceRecogniser class provided in OpenCV. It is quite robust with accuracy more than 90%. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't consider myself to be the expert in CV, but I have dabbled a bit to point you to the right literature.

Look at this paper for a survey of work used in human gender recognition from face images:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1611.pdf

Also look at following papers:
http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/GenderRecognitionIWSSIP12.pdf
http://tdlc.ucsd.edu/research/publications/Nestor_Tarr_Gender_Recognition.pdf
http://www.ijarcce.com/upload/2013/june/43-Hadeel%20Alrashed%20-facial%20gender%20recognition%20using%20eyes%20images.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it's useful for the algorithm research, but can anyone share some project experiences?